# Filter big CSV file and then take average of filtered values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a big CSV file with hundreds of thousands of rows. I want to filter the file based on row value and then take the average of the filtered files using pandas.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Let's pick a minimum reproducible example to showcase how various constraints can be used to filter rows from the dataframe. For simplicity, let's pick a two-column dataframe with 20 periodically repeating entries. With the multiplier `N` that concatenates the two lists 50,000 times each, this frame has exactly 1 million rows.

```
# Example dataframe
N = 50000
df_big = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : [7,2, 24,1, 27,15,7,27,26,10,7,2,10,8,4,5,17,10,3,28]*N, 
                       'col2' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]*N})
```

Now, we can apply various constraints (equality, inequality, or function-based) that can be associated via `and` (i.e. `&`) / `or` (i.e. `|` operator as seen below. After sequentially slicing out the rows for which any of the constraints does not hold, we can apply `.mean()` to obtain the desired result.

```
# inequality constraints
df_big = df_big[(df_big['col1'] > 5) & (df_big['col1'] <= 15)]

# equality constraints
df_big = df_big[(df_big['col1'] == 10) | (df_big['col1'] == 7)]

# function-based condition
df_big = df_big[df_big['col1'].apply(isPrime)]

df_mean = df_big.mean()
```

which yields

```
col1    7.000000
col2    6.333333
dtype: float64
```

How long does this take? Less than a single second. Precisely `765 ms`.

EDIT: Here the method `isPrime()` used above:

```
def isPrime(x:int):
    assert i>0
    if x==1:
        return False
    elif x==2:
        return True
    else:
        return not(any([x%i==0 for i in range(2,x,1)]))
```